# Google Pay is not Available in API 28

Tags: android, android-studio, google-pay

I am using Googles example for google pay . The link is bellow

https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart

But the problem is its working in every api Except API 28 (Android pie ) .Here is code ,

```
Task<Boolean> task = mPaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request);
task.addOnCompleteListener(this,
    new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          setGooglePayAvailable(task.getResult());
        } else {
          Log.w("isReadyToPay", task.getException());
        }
      }
    });
```

}

Here isReadyToPay returning false for api 28 . Can anyone help ?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: whats the error in `api 28`, paste `stackTrace` as well

Comment: Thanks for reply . I have  checked the stackTrace . There is no error . But unfortunately it's not working in api 28 .  I have used googles code .

Comment: Try using `task.addOnSuccessListener()` and `task.addOnFailureListener()`, I believe it should return cause for the error.

Comment: Thanks for reply  . Actually the task is successful . But task.getResult() return false only in Api 28 . I don't know why .

Comment: Are you saying that it returns `true` in versions less than or greater than 28? How are you testing? Is this via an emulator? Can you point the device browser at: https://jsfiddle.net/edckt46s/ (it sucks on the phone, scroll to the right and see if the button appears - try for the different API versions that you've previously tried as well)

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I checked task.getResult() . It returns false for API 28 (Android pie ) and return true for other api .

Comment: Can you try it against the web version of the Google Pay button: https://jsfiddle.net/edckt46s/ see if you get the same result? (see my previous comment)

Comment: Also, how are you testing? Physical device or emulator?

Comment: Thanks for reply again . I will try to follow your instruction and  i have tested in both physical device and emulator .